# Reordering articles in blog category

Tags: joomla-3.4, article-manager

there is an article (quite old) that is always on top, even after changing the ordering option to newest first. I did the following:

1) Global Configuration -> Articles -> Shared Options
Article Order (Newest First), Date for Ordering (Published)

2) Blog/Featured Layout -> #leading articles (1)

3) Article options (for the older article) - I checked that it was not a featured article and the options were the same as per the other articles, all set to Use Global.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance
Larry

Comment: I found the problem. It was because I did a save as new for an older article and it took the published date for that older article.

Comment: Can you add as an answer and mark as complete please? :)